# Flutter: Convert string to Map

Tags: json, sqlite, flutter, sqflite

I am using SQFlite to store data locally, I have a table in which I have a field called 'json', this field is of type TEXT and stores a json converted to String, such as: '{name: Eduardo, Age: 23, Sex: male}'.

Up to this point, everything works fine.

But then I need to consult this information from the database and how it is stored in a text type format flutter recognizes it as a string. I don't know how to convert it back to an object.
I know that I can build a function to solve this, in the case that the information stored in the json always complies with the same structure. But in my case, the information contained by the json will be variable.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@EduardoColon If the keys are not quoted, then it's not JSON, it's your own custom key-value format. JSON keys have to be quoted. See https://json.org for the "official" JSON syntax.

Answer (score 4):

you can Simply use json.decode function from the dart:convert package.

example:

```
import 'dart:convert';

main() {
  final jsonString = '{"key1": 1, "key2": "hello"}';
  final decodedMap = json.decode(jsonString);

  // we can now use the decodedMap as a normal map
  print(decodedMap['key1']); 
}
```

check those links for more details

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.3/dart-convert/json-constant.html

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.4.0/dart-convert/dart-convert-library.html

Comment: I already tried it, but my problem is that my string doesnt have quotes in the keys, so this function throws me  'unexpected character found' error

Comment: @EduardoColon  please take a look at the new answer i wrote, i tested it and it worked, the code replaces the non-quoted strings with quoted one , and then work with them easily

Comment: this will not work , since the string doesn't have quotes..

Answer (score 3):

if you have issue  that your json keys doesn't have quotes then try this code it transform the unquoted String to a quoted String and then decode it , it's 100% working

```
final string1 = '{name : "Eduardo", numbers : [12, 23], country: us }';

// remove all quotes from the string values
final string2=string1.replaceAll("\"", "");

// now we add quotes to both keys and Strings values
final quotedString = string2.replaceAllMapped(RegExp(r'\b\w+\b'), (match) {
  return '"${match.group(0)}"';
});

// decoding it as a normal json
  final decoded = json.decode(quotedString);
  print(decoded);
```

Comment: This will not work if there is a word with a space i.e. "One Two"

Comment: @Almog have you solve the space problem ? i dont see any answer to this problem

Comment: @Pif I did something else at the end